# Convert IGrouping to IDictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, group-by

I have the following grouping as result of a database-query:

```
5: Key1
3: Key2, Key3, Key4
2: Key5
1: Key6, Key7
```

I want the top x (whereas `x` is user-defined) by the groupings key as a dictionary.

For Top 3 I want a Dictionary

```
Key1: 5
Key2: 3
Key3: 3
Key4: 3
Key5: 2
```

and for Top 2 I want

```
Key1: 5
Key2: 3
Key3: 3
Key4: 3
```

and for top 1 only

```
Key1: 5
```

How can I convert the `IGrouping<int, string>` into a `IDictionary<string, int>`.
Note: The Keys are unique.

Comment: Can you explain more what you mean by "For Top 3"? You mean you want to create a dictionary based on the first N results from your database?

Comment: I want the top 3 distinct by the grouping's key (which may be more than only 3 in case the key has more than one matching keys)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you get the "Top N" groups by calling `Take`:

```
groups.Take(n)
```

then flatten to a list of value-key pairs

```
      .SelectMany(g => g, (g, k) => new {Value = g.Key, Key = k})
```

then just call `ToDictionary`:

```
      .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!